# how can i create custom edit button using apex class?

Tags: community

how can i create custom edit button?

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!editRecord}" value="Edit"/>
```

Class

```
public pageReference editRecord(){
        PageReference errorPage = new PageReference('/apex/ContactInsert?id='+conId);
        errorPage.setRedirect(true);
        return errorPage;
    }
```

Comment: means you want to redirect to standard edit page?

Comment: yes i want to redirect custom edit page but action value is editRecord not edit

Answer (score 5):

You don't even need a controller for this (or any Apex Code). You can write your buttons as follows:

```
<!-- Delete Button -->
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.Delete, Contact.Id, null, true)}" value="Delete" />
<!-- Edit Button -->
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.Edit, Contact.Id, null, true)}" value="Edit" />
```

You can learn more about the [$Action variable](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_action_values.htm&language=en) in the online help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method in your controller and pass contact id and use

```
delete [select id from contact where id =: conId];
```

Comment: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0032800000AN3FBAA1; first error: DELETE_FAILED, Your attempt to delete Mr. Timm Barr could not be completed because it is associated with the following cases.: 00001007, 00001008 : []

Comment: Yes that's the standard salesforce functionality. you will not be able to delete the record where some cases are associated.

Comment: Then what is the solution?

Comment: <apex:commandButton action="{!deleteRecord}" value="Delete" reRender="myId" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){return};" />

Comment: public pageReference deleteRecord(){
     Id  delid=standardController.getID();
     delete [select id from contact where id =: delId];
      Map<string,schema.Sobjecttype> gd = schema.getGlobalDescribe();
      String strKeyPrefix = gd.get('Contact').getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
      system.debug(strKeyPrefix);
      PageReference contPage = new pagereference('/'+strKeyPrefix+'/o');
      contPage.setRedirect(true);
      return contPage;}

Comment: I believe you have to delete those cases first to delete this contact record

Comment: can you give me a proper solution

Comment: @SachinGoyal if you want to delete any contact record that has some associated cases then use **delete [select id from case where contactid =: conid]** and then write your contact delete statement.